# How to implement facebook wall?

Tags: 7, social-network

Is there any module which works the same as facebook's user wall?

On facebook's wall, users can post/share anything and friends can also post/comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to do it without statuses. But I used formblock, rules, heartbeat.

1. I created a content type wall post with user reference field and body field.
2. I showed the node/add/wall-post block on profile page using formblock.
3. I created form_alter to set default value of user reference field to profile autor id.
4. I hid the user reference field using css.
5. I created the rule "redirect user to profile page after saving wall post" so that when user post it will come back to same profile.
6. I cloned the heartbeat template "heartbeat_add_node" to create "heartbeat_add_wall_post" and set its content to "!username has posted on !username2 wall. !node_body".
7. I updated above rule and added one more action "log a user activity" = heartbeat_add_wall_post". Set the Entity ID to [node:nid], User ID to [node:author:uid], User target ID to [node:my-user_reference_filed] and provided the values for !username, !username2 and !node_body.
8. And showed the user activity stream block on profile page. User can also comment the logged activity and heartbeat saved comments to original wall post.

Comment: Heartbeat is no longer on active development. They recommend using the message framework.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it's under development.  It's called [statuses](https://drupal.org/project/statuses).

Comment: Well, I tried this with statuses but it is very unstable and I am unable to post on other users wall.

Comment: Now we got a beta release and the core is stable enough. http://drupal.org/node/1709916

Comment: Statuses now works and seem stable.

Comment: @Druvision It may work now, but it still hasn't had a stable release for D7, so I think it's fair to say that it's still under development.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of modules that could help you, Although you would still have to write a bunch of custom modules and install bunch of modules.

start by downloading this module [fb module](http://drupal.org/project/fb)

theres another under dev module [statuses](https://drupal.org/project/statuses)

Comment: What would you use the fb module for?  As far as I know, the fb module is for integrating facebook and Drupal.  This question is about how to add a wall feature (not specifically facebook's wall) within Drupal.  Also, the fb module has no stable release for D7.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Disqus](http://drupal.org/project/disqus) module.

> DISQUS is a comments platform that helps you build an active community from your website's audience. It has awesome features, powerful tools, and it's easy to install.
>
> #### Disqus Features
>
> - Threaded comments and replies
> - Notifications and reply by email
> - Subscribe and RSS options
> - Aggregated comments and social mentions
> - Powerful moderation and admin tools
> - Full spam filtering, blacklists and whitelists
> - Support for Disqus community widgets
> - Connected with a large discussion community
> - Increased exposure and readership

Comment: In which way does the Disqus module help creating a Facebook wall?